# Windows has to check the registry while booting

Tags: windows, boot, windows-registry

When booting Windows, I always have to check the registry and sometimes I am forced to restart the computer. In addition to re-installing my Windows, is there another way to cope with the registry at boot time?

I worry my computer will become damaged on the system if it must restart it by force.

This is displayed:

> Chose advanced options for: Microsoft Vista (use the arrow keys to highlight your choice.)

```
safe mode
safe mode with networking
safe mode with command promt

enable boot logging
enable low-resolution video (640x480)
last known good configuration (advanced)
directory services restore mode
debugging mode
disable automatic restart on system failure
disable driver signature enforcement

start windows normally
```

> Description: Start Windows with only the core drivers and services. Use when you cannot boot after installing a new or driver.

Comment: I'm little confused at the last line with `installing a new or driver` what that mean? Also have you see that booting option normally every time?

Comment: Hahahahah that's a normal thing when your windows mess up any major crash or some other new crappy app you can choose `safe mode`. If you think it can run normally then you can select `Start Windows Normally`.

Comment: @avirk, I ask, how to eliminate registry, because I feel tired and distracted if i am have to check the registry and sometimes if too long I have to restart the computer!!

Comment: My apologies I still not understand completely that about which registry you are talking about? Do you want to remove the registry of a specific program? If you want to remove these  options from starting then I'm not sure its possible as I think it can't be achieve.

Comment: @slhck thanks for edit now I can understand the user that what he wants to do. Lol.

Comment: You are getting this message because there is a problem. You need to find the problem. have you chosen `Safe Mode` and allowed it to boot completely? Then when you do a normal restart does it still come to this menu?

Comment: What makes you think that your problem is related to the registry?